# Ruby on Rails Page not reloading on submit button click

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reload

I have an Approve button that changes `status` attribute of the `Shop` table record. When I click on it, it *does* change attribute, but it doesn't reload the page, so I have to reload page manually to see the result, which is very inconvenient. Looks like everything has to work, but page still not reloading.

My **view** has:

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @shop], remote: true, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }) do |fr| %>
  <%= fr.hidden_field :status, :value => 2 %>
  <%= fr.submit "Reject", class: "btn btn-large btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

And the **controller**:

```
  def update
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])

    if @shop.update_attributes(shop_params)
      flash[:success] = "Shop updated"
      redirect_to([:admin, @shop])
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

I would be grateful for any help, thank you!

Comment: remove `remote: true` from `form_for` if u want page to be reloaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `remote: true` in `form_for`, which is making your form submission via AJAX.

You may need to add `method: :put` so that form hits action `update` instead of `create`.

So just try removing `remote: true` and add `method: :put` as follow and try submitting form again.

```
<%= form_for([:admin, @shop], method: :put, data: { confirm: "You sure?" }) do |fr| %>
  <%= fr.hidden_field :status, :value => 2 %>
  <%= fr.submit "Reject", class: "btn btn-large btn-danger" %>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you are missing the respond_to do |format| calls or did you omitted them on the question?

should be like that:

```
  def update
    @shop = Shop.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
     if @shop.update(shop_params)
       format.html { redirect_to [:admin, @shop], notice: "Shop updated"
     else
       format.html { render action: 'edit' }
     end
   end  
  end
```

hope that helps.

Comment: No, that didn't help, but thanks for the suggestion!